# How to search numbers for a given set of repetitive numbers in random order the first time only?

Tags: search, random, sequence

How to search numbers for a given set of repetitive numbers in random order that occurs for the first time only. Say for rand() % 5 +1 which repeats n times till it finds all the numbers which occurs at the first time and the number of iteration it took to get all the numbers?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you give us an example. Also, which language (or at least: paradigm?)?

Comment: sorry about that, in C++ for example I want to choose set of numbers in an array and count howmany iteration it took to get all the numbers.

Comment: sorry about that, in C++ for example I want to choose set of numbers in an array and count in how many iteration it took to get all the numbers.                  array=[1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 ], rand(size_of_array) in how many iterations can i get the numbers 1 2 3 4,in this case its 7 but the same for n numbers with m frequencies of the numbers.